# PHP Arrays - form input

Tags: php, arrays, forms, submit

I need some help with PHP arrays.

I run a form, that sends this data:

```
$exposure = inputFilter($_POST['exposure']);
```

The value of EXPOSURE can either be: 1,2,3 or 4.

Each value (1,2,3 and 4) represents an exposure type. Example:

```
1 = micro
2 = mini
3 = standard
4 = extended
```

**My question is** how can I output this in an array?

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to output? You don't know how to build the array?

Comment: -1 I can't understand the question and i think I'm not the only one

Comment: So your getting the numbers 1-4 from the form and now you need to turn the numbers into micro, mini, etc... how are you getting them from the form? Input box, select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$exposure = inputFilter($_POST['exposure']);

$array = array(
    1 => 'micro',
    2 => 'mini',
    3 => 'standard',
    4 => 'extended'
);

echo $array[$exposure];
```

So when $exposure is 1, 'micro' is echoed, and so on.